# AvroCoder UnresolvedUnionException when inheriting

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, avro, apache-beam

I am modifying a class that will be used in my Dataflow Pipeline. I declared my default coder as `AvroCoder`.
The class works fine until i add inheritance to a static subclass `CompareEquals`. Now that `CompareEquals` extends `Comparisons`
I get this error...

```
    org.apache.avro.UnresolvedUnionException: Not in union ["null",{"type":"record","name":"Comparisons","namespace":"com.package.AttributeCompare$","fields":[]}]: com.package.AttributeCompare$CompareEquals@3688eb5b
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.resolveUnion(GenericData.java:740)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.resolveUnion(GenericDatumWriter.java:205)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeWithoutConversion(GenericDatumWriter.java:123)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:75)
        at org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectDatumWriter.write(ReflectDatumWriter.java:159) ...
```

Here are the classes (Both are in seperate files same package):

```
    @DefaultCoder(AvroCoder.class)
    public class AttributeCompare extends AttributeBase {

        public static class CompareEquals extends Comparisons implements Serializable{

            @Override
            public boolean isSatisfied(Object atrC, Object attr) {
                return true;
            };
        }
    }


    @DefaultCoder(AvroCoder.class)
    public class Comparisons implements Serializable {
      public boolean isSatisfied(Object atrC, Object attr);
    }
```

Without the `extends` it runs without error.  I have tried turning Comparisons into an interface and still the had same issue. Any suggestions on where to go from here?

Comment: Are you encoding AttributeCompare instances or CompareEquals instances? It seems like the latter, but your annotation is on the former.

Comment: Also: each PCollection has a single coder that's used for encoding/decoding all of its elements. If your PCollection consists of elements of different types, that's going to be troublesome: you need a single coder that can encode and decode any of these types. AvroCoder is specialized to the single particular class you apply it to. You can't use it on a PCollection of arbitrary subclasses of that class. In that case, just using Serializable is a better way to go